# Set try catch in $_GET to give a null return if not set in addressbar

Tags: php

Hi I'm currently building a page in PHP and I'm having a trouble on setting this one. It is currently running on my localhost. Well my page is in this folder

http://localhost/signup/signup/

named index.php so it is the front page. My goal is to use this one for database update wherein I manually key in the $_GET value in the addressbar of the browser which will now look like this

http://localhost/signup/signup/?email=email@yahoo.com.

This will fill up my forms with the user information based on their email. Now I have a problem on how can I set the $_GET value into null (or blank space) so that I can use 
http://localhost/signup/signup/ even without the email being set on the addressbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about something a bit better?

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))
   $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
else
   $email = "";
?>
```

That way it isn't set twice for no reason. and using $_REQUEST will allow for future changes in case you change it such that they give you that variable as part of a post. This way you wont have to rewrite a bunch of code.

Comment: this reminds me of register globals which is a universally bad idea.

Comment: Yes, except that $_REQUEST is well documented and easily understood. But I know what you mean. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$email = "";
if(isset($_GET['email'])){
  $email = $_GET['email'];
}
```

Comment: I think the answer above is the best for me, but also thanks for the answer. This might help me sometimes.